Google Identity Rest API Failed
I'm trying to access the Google Identity REST API for Firebase Authentication. After logging in with Firebase Admin SDK, I use:
const projectID = app.options.projectId;

const token = await app.options.credential?.getAccessToken();

if (!token) {
    throw 'No token!';
}

const url = `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectID}/accounts:query?alt=json`;
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "returnUserInfo": false,
        "expression": []
    })
};

return await fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json());

But I get this error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "VPCSC_CHECK_FAILED : Permission denied: Consumer 'project_number:{my-project-number}' has been suspended.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "VPCSC_CHECK_FAILED : Permission denied: Consumer 'project_number:{my-project-number}' has been suspended.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}


My project has not been suspended as far as I can see. Is this a permission problem? If so how do I fix this? I'm not using any restrictions or perimeter etc. Just a regular Firebase Account where Firebase Admin works as expected. Is there a certain IAM setting I need?

Below are the  few reasons can you cross check on it and validate it:

One of the reasons to get a suspended account is that if you are
using a free tier account, the credits might be exhausted and you need to pay the bill to re-enable the account and project.

Logging that was enabled on a “Firebase Authentication Legacy” in projects on or before 03/27/2023 cannot enable Google Cloud Identity Platform for the project. So, you should not use Google Cloud Identity Billing instead you need to use Firebase Auth Billing. Can you cross check and confirm whether Firebase Auth Billing is enabled or not.

As per this permission document , can you enable firebase.billingPlans.get and firebase.billingPlans.update in IAM roles.



Is my account Suspended? Everything works outside of this fetch. I am using the Blaze Plan, and I added Billing Account Usage Commitment Recommender Admin, and Project Billing Manager to my firebase-admin account and my personal gmail if that is what you mean. Still same error.


Google Cloud compliance will send you an email telling you why your project is being warned.


if you didn't get any warning to resolve your issue you need to contact google support and raise a ticket. If you don't have a billing account try Public Issue Tracker.

It turns out the typing is wrong. const projectID = app.options.projectId; should be app.options.credential.projectId;. The TS files for Firebase Admin need to be updated.
